# JTable resultset - how to populate a JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, resultset

I'm trying to put info from my Database into a `JTable`.

I've got a class that reads from my DB and the info is saved in a resultset.

In my other class (the GUI), I'm trying to put the resultset from the other class into this GUI class.

```
    try {
        table.setColumnModel((TableColumnModel) ClassSQL.DB());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I tried using the setModel - but that didn't work. The code above is what I currently have, but it's not working.

What am I doing wrong? I've worked with this a long time now; still no success.

Comment: have to search here, similair questions are daily asked here

Comment: everything depends of whats ClassSQL.DB() returns, did you test that, if not then why is this question asked here

Comment: it returns results.

I did search here - but couldn't find a proper answer. Have searched a lot; not just here :/

I actually got an error message when I used the above mentioned code. It says: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel
 at model ...

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel at model == this is true, you have to iterate/loop inside those two arrays, one is about colums, second (2D array) about real data, for more info to read Oracles tutorials about JDBC and how to use Tables, there is described everything for your success

Comment: See http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/